# How to make the gdb list only the threads that were in execution when the debugging program was interrupted?

Tags: gdb

I am debugging a program that has about 100 threads running on a 12 core processors. I want to view the stack of only those threads that were executing when the gdb interrupted the debugging program.

Comment: What do you mean by execution? Do you want to filter off threads that were waiting for IO when interrupted?

Comment: not necessarily waiting for IO. Some of the threads could be waiting for cpu time, I want to list only those threads that were in cpu when interrupted.